# Clear specific tabpage text boxes

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 4 tabs in my tabcontrol page. I want to clear all the textboxes in the last tab. However the code I am using only clears the texbox that is selected.

```
foreach (Control control in tabcontrol1.SelectedTab.Controls)
{
    TextBox text = control as TextBox;
    if (text != null)
    {
        text.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the tab only contains text-boxes? Otherwise your code gona break! better to check [Object.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) against the [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/58918ffs.aspx)

Comment: the last tab has all textboxes and one combo box

Comment: use `foreach (TextBox control in tabcontrol1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`

Comment: @Hardik Gondallia Works perfect one of the textboxes has color in it and is not being cleared. What alteration to the code do I make for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Try This: might be useful to you..

```
void ClearTextBoxes(Control parent)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            TextBox textBox = child as TextBox;
            if (textBox == null)
                ClearTextBoxes(child);
            else
                textBox.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void resetCurrentPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearTextBoxes(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find all textboxes in the last tab? You could use htis:

```
var allTxt = tabcontrol1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>().Last().Controls.OfType<TextBox>();

foreach(TextBox txt in allTxt)
    txt.Text = "";
```

(you need to add `using System.Linq`)

Answer (score 0):

Please, visit following link. You will get better explanation about how to use clear controls.
[Clear all textboxes in form with one Function](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/813516/Clear-all-textboxes-in-form-with-one-Function#answer3). Hope, it will be helpful for you.